# Arranging cells in the tableView by the time (HH:mm) specified in the cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

There is a tableView which initially should be empty. The user can add events (cells) by tapping the “+” button and filling out the form on a separate view controller (AddSession file). The form contains text fields for the beginning and ending time of the event, as well as the event’s name and venue. As soon as the user hits the add button in this form, I want the events in the tableView to arrange by time automatically. The later event should go to the bottom, and the earlier one should go to the top. Seems a bit complicated, and I am very new to coding. Each event has a beginning time and an ending time, so I can’t even start thinking of what should be compared during the sorting process. I assume there should be no time overlaps for two separate events, and I should probably think of how to restrict this as well. Otherwise, the whole tableView will turn up completely chaotic. So how can I do this auto-arranging/sorting procedure?

Here's the code for my main viewController:

```
import UIKit

class ParticularEventVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var sessionsTable: UITableView!
    
    var sessions: [sessionModel] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sessionsTable.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        sessions.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = sessionsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PrototypeCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! PrototypeCell
        
        let session = sessions[indexPath.row]
        cell.sessionBeginningTime.text = session.modelTimeBeginning
        cell.sessionEndingTime.text = session.modelTimeEnding
        cell.sessionName.text = session.modelSession
        cell.sessionVenue.text = session.modelVenue
        
        return cell
    }
    
    @IBAction func unwindToSessionsList(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        
        guard let vc = segue.source as? AddSession else {return}
        
        guard let timeBeginning = vc.timeBeginningTextField.text, let timeEnding = vc.timeEndingTextField.text, let ssn = vc.sessionNameTextField.text, let vn = vc.sessionVenueTextField.text else {return}
        
        let Session = sessionModel(modelTimeBeginning: timeBeginning, modelTimeEnding: timeEnding, modelSession: ssn, modelVenue: vn)
        
        sessions.append(Session)
        sessionsTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This is the code for adding a session:

```
import UIKit

class AddSession: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timeBeginningTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeEndingTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sessionNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sessionVenueTextField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func cancelAddSession(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToSessionsList", sender: self)}
    @IBAction func addSession(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToSessionsList", sender: self)}
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // MARK: Filling the beginning time with the datepicker
        let timeB = Date()
        let formatterTB = DateFormatter()
        formatterTB.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        timeBeginningTextField.text = formatterTB.string(from: timeB)
        let timePickerB = UIDatePicker()
        timePickerB.datePickerMode = .time
        timePickerB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timePickerBValueChanged(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        timePickerB.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        timePickerB.frame.size = CGSize(width: 0, height: 250)
        timeBeginningTextField.inputView = timePickerB
        
        // MARK: Filling the ending time with the datepicker
        let timeE = Date()
        let formatterTE = DateFormatter()
        formatterTE.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        timeEndingTextField.text = formatterTE.string(from: timeE)
        let timePickerE = UIDatePicker()
        timePickerE.datePickerMode = .time
        timePickerE.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timePickerEValueChanged(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        timePickerE.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        timePickerE.frame.size = CGSize(width: 0, height: 250)
        timeEndingTextField.inputView = timePickerE
    }
    
    @objc func timePickerBValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let FormatterTB = DateFormatter()
        FormatterTB.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        timeBeginningTextField.text = FormatterTB.string(from: sender.date)}
    
    @objc func timePickerEValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let formatterTE = DateFormatter()
        formatterTE.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        timeEndingTextField.text = formatterTE.string(from: sender.date)}
}
```

This is the code for my prototype cell (don't know if you need it):

```
import UIKit

class PrototypeCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var sessionBeginningTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sessionEndingTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sessionName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sessionVenue: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()}

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)}
}
```

And this is the code for my session model:

```
import Foundation

struct sessionModel {
    let modelTimeBeginning: String
    let modelTimeEnding: String
    let modelSession: String
    let modelVenue: String
}
```

[[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP690.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sWrP.png)

Also, response to your answers (NeZha and OneComment guy) (don't know where to put it):

Thanks a lot for the response and the solution! As I've said before, I am very new to coding, so I don't have this intuitive understanding of what you're offering, lol. I mostly watch YouTube tutorials and try to employ their methods for my purposes. As for what you’ve said, I gave it a whirl and changed:

```
let modelTimeBeginning: String
let modelTimeEnding: String
```

to

```
let modelTimeBeginning: Date
let modelTimeEnding: Date
```

in my model struct. But it caused a whole bunch of new issues.

For instance here:

```
let session = sessions[indexPath.row]
    cell.beginningTime.date = session.modelTimeBeginning
    cell.endingTime.date = session.modelTimeEnding
    return cell
```

it says " Value of type 'UILabel' has no member 'date' "

and here:

```
guard let vc = segue.source as? AddSession else {return}
guard let timeBeginning = vc.beginningTimeDatePicker.date, let timeEnding = vc.endingTimeDatePicker.date, let ssn = vc.eventTextField.text else {return}
let Session = Model(modelTimeBeginning: timeBeginning, modelTimeEnding: timeEnding, modelSession: ssn)
    sessions.append(Session)
    sessionsTable.reloadData()
```

it says “Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Date' ”

As far as I understood, I am converting Date to String in order to fill in the textfield. So the sorting should be done somewhere before I do the conversion, right? God, this coding stuff is so confusing.

Comment: You should store the date as Date type in Swift, which supports compare by > or < operator. It would help if you compared the event's end time for each inserts new event at the precondition of no overlap timespan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its own file

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static let friendlyDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

In its own file

```
    struct Model {
        var modelTimeBeginning: Date?
        var modelTimeEnding: Date?
        var modelSession: String?
        var modelVenue: String?
    
        var friendlyStartTime: String {
            guard let text = modelTimeBeginning else { return "" }
            return DateFormatter.friendlyDateFormatter.string(from: text)
        }

    var friendlyEndTime: String {
        guard let text = modelTimeEnding else { return "" }
        return DateFormatter.friendlyDateFormatter.string(from: text)
    }
}
```

In your class AddSession: VC have a public struct of

```
var session = Model()
```

When,

```
timeBeginningTextField.text = FormatterTB.string(from: sender.date)}
```

do.

```
session.modelTimeEnding = sender.date
timeBeginningTextField.text = session.friendlyEndTime
```

When,

```
guard let vc = segue.source as? AddSession else {return}
guard let timeBeginning = vc.beginningTimeDatePicker.date,
        let timeEnding = vc.endingTimeDatePicker.date,
        let ssn = vc.eventTextField.text else {return}

let Session = Model(modelTimeBeginning: timeBeginning, modelTimeEnding: timeEnding, modelSession: ssn)
    sessions.append(Session)
    sessionsTable.reloadData()
```

do,

```
guard let vc = segue.source as? AddSession else {return}



sessions.append(vc.session)
sessions.sort { $0.date < $1.date }
sessionsTable.reloadData()
```

Comment: Updated sessionModel as you said. Now it says "Cannot find 'dateFormatter' in scope" for both friendlyStartTime and friendlyEndTime. Where do I put the extension? Also now in the singleEvent.swift file, where I put "let Session = sessionModel(timeBeginningModel: timeBeginning, timeEndingModel: timeEnding, sessionModel: ssn, venueModel: vn)" it returns Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Date'

Comment: To put it simply, I am trying to pass on the beginning and ending time from datePickers to respective textFields. And then from these textFields to labels on a separate vc. Somewhere in between, I need to do the sorting

Comment: Ive updated by response. If this doesn't help, I advise reading into structs and how to use them to pass data and populate views. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much @OneCommentMan!!! It really did help a lot! I'm almost there. I hope you stumble across a suitcase full of cash in the nearest future =)

Comment: You can make my response the accepted answer :P

Comment: Don’t know how to do that either  Let me figure this out

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, have date as a Date type in your session struct.
Then when you

```
sessions.append(Session)
sessions.sort { $0.date < $1.date } //Add this line,
sessionsTable.reloadData()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It says " Cannot assign value of type 'Date' to type 'String?' "

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps.